# VBscript to display all values in a column separated by a comma?

Tags: sql, vbscript

I want to display all email addresses from a column (named email) separated by a comma in html.  How would I write a sql query in an html page?

Comment: Literally in an Html page? Html pages are static. Thus, you cannot do it dynamically (i.e. you must know the addresses ahead of time). Are you sure you do not mean in an ASP Classic page?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a writeup on it with good notes:
http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Concatenate_Values_From_Multiple_Rows_Into_One_Column